# Python: Iterating over list of dictionaries and output to a list

Tags: python

I am looping over the json object and output of the object is in the form of lists of dictionaries.

```
[{'Status': 'active', 'id': '0f1fb86da9c7ee380'}]
[{'Status': 'active', 'id': '0d6b330e4960c3382'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '033cfb634e595ccfa'}]
[{'Status': 'active', 'id': '0457f623cbb9f7c95'}]
[{'Status': 'active', 'id': '01b69eb6a3048f749'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '0f7ce44a9a5fc82f5'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '05417e161acf3ec5d'}]
[{'Status': 'active', 'id': '033cfb634e595ccfa'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '01eab32f9808acf19'}]
```

I have tried something like this so far but it prints in the form of string. I tried using list and appending it but it gives me a weird output. If I don't use list then it gives me the list of all in the form of strings.

Current output:

```
0f1fb86da9c7ee380
0d6b330e4960c3382
033cfb634e595ccfa
0457f623cbb9f7c95
01b69eb6a3048f749
0f7ce44a9a5fc82f5
05417e161acf3ec5d
0f373f123dc8221de
05417e161acf3ec5d
```

My code:

```py
    for i in data['DBI']:
        t = 0
         while t < len(i['Groups']):
             print i['Groups'][t]['id']
             t += 1`
```

Expected Output: I am looking for the output in the form of the list like this `['0f1fb86da9c7ee380'] ['0d6b330e4960c3382','033cfb634e595ccfa'] ['0457f623cbb9f7c95'] ['01b69eb6a3048f749','0f7ce44a9a5fc82f5',''05417e161acf3ec5d'] ['033cfb634e595ccfa','01eab32f9808acf19']`

Comment: Expected Output:
I am looking for the output in the form of the list like this
['0f1fb86da9c7ee380']
['0d6b330e4960c3382','033cfb634e595ccfa']
['0457f623cbb9f7c95']
['01b69eb6a3048f749','0f7ce44a9a5fc82f5',''05417e161acf3ec5d']
['033cfb634e595ccfa','01eab32f9808acf19']

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question (you can edit your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```
data = [ 
    [{'Status': 'active', 'id': '0f1fb86da9c7ee380'}], 
    [{'Status': 'active', 'id': '0d6b330e4960c3382'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '033cfb634e595ccfa'}], 
    [{'Status': 'active', 'id': '0457f623cbb9f7c95'}], 
    [{'Status': 'active', 'id': '01b69eb6a3048f749'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '0f7ce44a9a5fc82f5'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '05417e161acf3ec5d'}], 
    [{'Status': 'active', 'id': '033cfb634e595ccfa'}, {'Status': 'active', 'id': '01eab32f9808acf19'}], 
]   

new_data = [] 
   for l in data: 
       current_ids = [] 
       for d in l: 
           current_ids.append(d["id"]) 
       new_data.append(current_ids) 
new_data
```

output:

```
[['0f1fb86da9c7ee380'],
 ['0d6b330e4960c3382', '033cfb634e595ccfa'],
 ['0457f623cbb9f7c95'],
 ['01b69eb6a3048f749', '0f7ce44a9a5fc82f5', '05417e161acf3ec5d'],
 ['033cfb634e595ccfa', '01eab32f9808acf19']]
```

Comment: Thank you Lahsuk for replying. I think I realized what I was doing wrong. I was keeping the empty list outside of the main loop so it was not resetting and keep appending on top of the existing elements. Here is what worked for me.   data =json.loads(v_string)
for id in data['DBI']:
  datalist = id['Groups']
  i=0
  data_list=[]   #<-- This was outside above man for loop.
  while i < len(datalist):
    for dic in datalist[i]:
       data_list.append(datalist[i][dic])
          print(data_list)
    i+=1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension to achieve this.

```
output = [[item["id"] for item in items] for items in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data =json.loads(v_string)
for id in data['DBI']:
  datalist = id['Groups']
  i=0
  data_list=[]   #<-- This was outside above mann for loop.
  while i < len(datalist):
    for dic in datalist[i]:
          if 'active' not in datalist[i][dic]:
          data_list.append(datalist[i][dic])
          print(data_list)
    i+=1
```